# How to validate values entered in a multiline Excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I receive a spreadsheet from a process that puts all of the values in 1 cell as multiline. I need to write a formula to validate that each line within that cell follows a specific format.

For example, the following values are all in 1 cell and I need to validate that each line follows the format:

- 3 digits (123)
- 7 digits (1234567)
- 4 digits (1234)
- 4 digits (1234)
- 2 digits.2digits (12.12).

```
123 1234567 1234    1234    12.12345678
123 1234568 1234    1234    12.12
123 1234569 1234    1234    12.12345678
123 1234560 1234    1234    12.12
```

Comment: Are the spaces between tabs or spaces, you have both in your test output.

Comment: Also what would be the result you expect?

Comment: Have you considered splitting the data into multiple cells?

Comment: It has tabs and spaces. I unfortunately don't have control over the file I receive.

Answer (score 2):

Going by given sample data and current explanation, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

`=AND(BYROW(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ","
",1),LAMBDA(x,SUM((LEN(x)={3,7,4,4,5})ISNUMBER(-x)(MID(TAKE(x,-1),3,1)=".")))))`

Or, written a bit more sane:

```
=AND(BYROW(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ",CHAR(10),1),LAMBDA(x,SUM((LEN(x)={3,7,4,4,5})*ISNUMBER(-x)*(MID(TAKE(x,-1),3,1)=".")))))
```

Comment: I went with line by line using TEXTJOIN: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,BYROW(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ",CHAR(10)),LAMBDA(a,SUM((LEN(a)={3,7,4,4,5})*(ISNUMBER(--a))*(MID(INDEX(a,,5),3,1)="."))=5)))` Been waiting for clarification.  Otherwise I am identical.

Comment: @ScottCraner, you came up with something so similar. That does please me, makes me think I could be on the right track here =)